# SWIFT restore program from dock in mac os

Tags: swift, macos

I'm trying to track the work of someone else’s program and if someone else’s program Minimize to the Dock, I’m trying to restore it back.

Tried the following code for this, but nothing happens:

```
let runningApps = NSRunningApplication.runningApplicationsWithBundleIdentifier("org.programmname")
if !runningApps.isEmpty {
    runningApps.first?.unhide()
}
```

The following is the window status verification code:

```
let options = CGWindowListOption(arrayLiteral: CGWindowListOption.OptionAll)
let windowListInfo = CGWindowListCopyWindowInfo(options, CGWindowID(0))
let infoList = windowListInfo as NSArray? as? [[String: AnyObject]]

for window in  infoList!{                       
                if window?.lowercaseString.rangeOfString("AppWindowName") != nil {
                      if window ["kCGWindowIsOnscreen"] == nil {
                        // the window is minimized 
                        let runningApps  = NSRunningApplication.runningApplicationsWithBundleIdentifier("org.programmname")
                        if !runningApps.isEmpty {
                            runningApps.first?.unhide()
                        }
                      } else {
                        //the window is visible
                      }
                }
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Is your app sandboxed? Does `runningApps` actually contain a value? Where are you calling this piece of code from, does it actually get hit when another app gets minimised?

Comment: Is the question about unhiding an app or deminiaturizing a window?

Comment: @Willeke deminiaturizing a window

Comment: @Dávid Pásztor Yes, runningApps contains a value, and the code works if the program window is “hidden”, but does not work if it is “minimized”.